# Calling Begin/EndInvoke on Action and Func in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, action, func

Does anyone know why I can't call BeginInvoke / EndInvoke on Action and Func delegates in my Silverlight app?  I keep getting a NotSupportedException.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you post a small example, the only BeginInvoke method available is on the `Dispatcher` but there is no EndInvoke.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Dispatcher for that.

Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is the method you want :).

It accepts Funcs and Actions